# Spring and Hibernate - changing dialect

Tags: spring, hibernate

In our web app that uses Spring and Hibernate, the hibernate configuration is in the `META-INF/persistence.xml`, but there is one problem, we are using two different databases, one for testing and other one for production.

Here is our `persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="SpringMVCTest" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/sqliteDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.model.UserEntity</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.model.WordList</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.model.WordUnit</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.model.ActivateUserAccountPermaLink</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.model.ResetPasswordPermaLink</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.question.QuestionUnit</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.question.OpenQuestion</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.question.MultipleChoiceQuestion</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.question.WithGapsQuestion</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.question.QuestionList</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.answer.AnswerUnit</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.answer.OpenQuestionAnswer</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.answer.MultipleChoiceQuestionAnswer</class>
        <class>pl.meble.taboret.answer.WithGapsQuestionAnswer</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${database.driver}"
                /> <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="${database.url}" /> -->

        <!--     <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/> -->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.AtomikosJTATransactionFactory"/> -->
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

so, is it possible to change the value of `hibernate.properties` at runtime, or store this value for example in `JNDI` resource?

Or is there some other way to conditionally set `hibernate.dialect`, so for example for testing we would have SQLite dialect and for normal deploy he would use Postgre dialect.

Comment: you can check here for sloution of this problem[click here ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166150/hibernate-jta-read-db-connection-parameters-per-environment/33309337#33309337)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In spring you define the entity manager with a bean:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
```

You can configure properties of that bean:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
</property>
```

where `${hibernate.dialect}` is spring property. So you can pass the property when starting your project (either via -Dhibernate.dialect, or by placing it in a properties file and loading it with `<context:property-placeholder-configurer>`

Comment: It works I think, but I have a question, your snippet worked, but when I try `property name="hibernate.dialect" value="pl.meble.taboret.utils.SQLiteDialect"/>` I am getting `Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]`. What is the difference? Both should set up properties?

Comment: nope - `<property name=..` is a property (field with setter/getter) of the bean itself. The JPA properties are set in `jpaProperties`, which is a `Map` in the (factory) bean

Comment: Ok thanks, I just fought that jpaProperties name wasn't meaningful in any way.