# Spring - setting property value from JNDI

Tags: spring, properties, jndi

It is a bit of followup to my previous question
[Spring and Hibernate - changing dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177423/spring-and-hibernate-changing-dialect/12178432#comment16303596_12178432)

if for example I have this piece of .xml

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpringMVCTest" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >

            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

now, I wanted to set `hibernate.dialect` to value that is exposed by jndi by `jdbc/dialect`, but when I put `<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>` I am getting `Invalid content was found starting with element 'jee:jndi-lookup'. No child element is expected at this` so I suspect that I can't put any tags in `prop`.

So, is there any way I can insert jndi resource to this property?

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure, but you should be able to use Spring-EL here, like this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dialect" jndi-name="..." />


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpringMVCTest" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect" >#{dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```